# ggplot - Plotting 2 different variables with the same x axis but with different color/shape for these 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a graph with date in x axis and pH values on y axis (AM = morning measures and PM = afternoon measures). In my data.frame I have 4 columns : mean_pHAM, sd_pHAM, mean_pHPM and sd_pHPM.

Here it's my code using Rstudio ```

```
pH1 <- ggplot(para_list_floc) +
  aes(x = Date, y = Moy_pHAM) +
  geom_point(size=3, color="blue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin =Moy_pHAM-Ecart_type_pHAM, ymax=Moy_pHAM +Ecart_type_pHAM),position=position_dodge(0.05), color="blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Date, y=Moy_pHPM,size=3, color="red",)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin =Moy_pHPM-Ecart_type_pHPM, ymax=Moy_pHPM +Ecart_type_pHPM),position=position_dodge(0.05), color="red") +
  ggtitle("Suivi du pH pendant la phase test") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10,hjust = 0.5,face="bold")) +
  ylab("Moy du pH/bac") + 
  labs(x = "Temps (en jour)") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Like you can see on the picture, I don't know how to have the same size of point but with colors different to see the values from AM and the values from PM measures. And also how to precise that in the legend?

[image]

> dput(head(para_list_floc,7))
> structure(list(Date = structure(8:14, .Label = c("Jour 01", "Jour 02",
> "Jour 03", "Jour 04", "Jour 05", "Jour 06", "Jour 07", "Jour 08",
> "Jour 09", "Jour 10", "Jour 11", "Jour 12", "Jour 13", "Jour 14",
> "Jour 15", "Jour 16", "Jour 17", "Jour 18", "Jour 19", "Jour 20",
> "Jour 21", "Jour 22", "Jour 23", "Jour 24", "Jour 25", "Jour 26",
> "Jour 27", "Jour 28", "Jour 29"), class = "factor"), Moy_tpAM = c(25.9428571428571,
> 25.8142857142857, 25.6571428571429, 25.9, 25.9, 25.9333333333333,
> 25.8047619047619), Ecart_type_tpAM = c(0.120712172424444, 0.101418510567422,
> 0.116496474502143, 0.104880884817015, 0.0999999999999998, 0.115470053837925,
> 0.139557122627942), Moy_tpPM = c(NaN, NaN, 26.1190476190476,
> 26.3285714285714, 26.3333333333333, 26.2761904761905, 26.1095238095238
> ), Ecart_type_tpPM = c(NA, NA, 0.132736760616823, 0.118923745075814,
> 0.119721899973786, 0.157812426331902, 0.175797502555531), Moy_pHAM = c(7.7452380952381,
> 7.58952380952381, 7.75904761904762, 7.69047619047619, 7.74190476190476,
> 7.70904761904762, 7.76333333333333), Ecart_type_pHAM = c(0.0705421184555048,
> 0.0633621488332104, 0.0659473094147715, 0.0644574425862669, 0.076001253122501,
> 0.0599920629670926, 0.0486141268905791), Moy_pHPM = c(NaN, NaN,
> 7.69285714285714, 7.75285714285714, 7.79380952380952, 7.78142857142857,
> 7.85666666666667), Ecart_type_pHPM = c(NA, NA, 0.0590883116312234,
> 0.0551491484197949, 0.0634410112211486, 0.0467210567395167, 0.0531350480693614
> ), Moy_Oxy = c(5.11714285714286, 5.21380952380952, 5.79380952380952,
> 5.68666666666667, 5.76571428571429, 5.65428571428571, NaN), Ecart_type_Oxy = c(0.181635427633016,
> 0.122901431662784, 0.176818443338815, 0.144890763450723, 0.161200850759896,
> 0.164971859072129, NA), Moy_MES = c(NaN, NaN, 4.47619047619048,
> 6.66666666666667, 5.45238095238095, 11, 6.14285714285714), Ecart_type_MES = c(NA,
> NA, 3.18777426457784, 2.42212028327799, 2.68283787203384, 1.4142135623731,
> 2.28113380330296), y = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
> TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: I did it, it is ok for you ? (I never used this function before)

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure does not easily lend itself to plotting with groupwise colors and dodging. You should reshape it into long format, with one column for mean value, one column for the error size, and one column for the variable (pHAM or pHPM). This means you only need a single `geom_point` call, a single `geom_errorbar` call, and allows you map the color to the variable (pHAM or pHPM). This can be done using the tidyverse functions `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

read.csv("paratest2.csv", sep = ";") %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(Moy_pHAM = mean(pH_AM, na.rm = TRUE),
            Moy_pHPM = mean(pH_PM, na.rm = TRUE),
            Ecart_type_pHAM = sd(pH_AM, na.rm = TRUE),
            Ecart_type_pHPM = sd(pH_PM, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(Date > "Jour 07") %>%
  pivot_longer(-Date, names_pattern = "^(.*)_(.*$)", 
             names_to = c("measure", "var")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = measure, values_from = value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Moy, color = var)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Moy - Ecart_type, ymax = Moy + Ecart_type),
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  ggtitle("Suivi du pH pendant la phase test") +
  labs(x = "Temps (en jour)", y = "Moy du pH/bac", color = NULL) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I put my data in my question (in case). I have inn my data frame one column for mean values, error size etc. I don't know this function :  pivot_longer(-Date, names_pattern = "^(.*)_(.*$)", 
             names_to = c("measure", "var")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = measure, values_from = value) %>%

Comment: @ank I have modified the code slightly in view of your example data. You can see this gives the expected output. If you run the exact code above by copying and pasting your console, you should get the desired result

Comment: @ank the pivot functions are in the tidyr package, which is part of the tidyverse. They are very useful for getting your data into a tidy format for making plotting simpler, and are great functions to learn.

Comment: Ok but I'm new with R, and it's very difficult to know how to construct the code to be efficient.. and it doesnt work R said to me : Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 2 provided. I think it's because it gave only 7 rows of my data.frame for example and your response if these 7 rows no ?

Comment: @ank did you try it with the updated code?

Comment: Yes @Allan Cameron

Comment: @ank then your error doesn't make any sense to me, since there should only be two factor levels with the code above, no matter how many rows your data frame has. My code was updated, and the first version would have given you the error you describe, but the version that is in the answer now shouldn't give you that error. Could you please try copy & pasting the above code block into your console and seeing if you still get the error? If you do, perhaps share the whole data frame either here or in a Dropbox?

Comment: No it's not work, here a link with my data and all my code. I don't know if you will understand what I made..https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/fjnl4eduded8vk8lf4c4p/h?dl=0&rlkey=q4tmzjr6thm8jxszpajmuguqr

Comment: @ank I downloaded your file to my home directory. Now running the above code gives me the output shown. Can you try the above code please?